# How should I open my html files from vs code ubuntu on google chrome?

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox, google-chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How should I open my html files from vs code ubuntu on google chrome? I have watched a couple of videos and also have installed the related extensions

I have checked on ubuntu whether there is any error in the installation of google_chrome by entering the command "google-chrome --version" it gives "Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198" but still when I want to open my html files from vs code to google-chrome. It gives an error. Following is the list of errors I got when I tried to change the name of the browser to open my html files. I have watched a video "https://youtu.be/N9_XD3Tgl5I" having the same error but the person had used firefox instead of google-chrome. I tried to apply the same procedure by using the word google-chrome in place of firefox by trying different methods of writing it but every time it gave me the following errors:
Kindly check the above video so that you can understand my problem in a better way.

**When I entered gogle-chrome** "[Running] google-chrome $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
[3590:3590:0716/180848.468758:ERROR:browser_dm_token_storage_linux.cc(100)] Error: /etc/machine-id contains 0 characters (32 were expected).
[3590:3617:0716/180848.622877:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[3590:3590:0716/180848.698761:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[3590:3590:0716/180848.698828:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.368 seconds

**When I entered Google only**[Running] Google $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
/bin/sh: 1: Google: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.071 seconds

**When I entered Chrome only**[Running] Chrome $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
/bin/sh: 1: Chrome: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.071 seconds

**When I entered Google Chrome**[Running] Google Chrome $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
/bin/sh: 1: Google: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.068 seconds

**When I entered Google-Chrome**[Running] Google-Chrome $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
/bin/sh: 1: Google-Chrome: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.077 seconds

**When I entered google_chrome**[Running] google_chrome $filename "/home/mamoona/html-practice/hello-html/html-hello-world.html"
/bin/sh: 1: google_chrome: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.066 seconds"

Then, I thought of installing firefox to ubuntu as people do not run html file like this now days. People now use live servers. But I am still unable to install firefox by using sudo snap install firefox command as gives me an error message:
"mamoona@DESKTOP-JIVR4K5:~$ sudo apt install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version (1:1snap1-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
mamoona@DESKTOP-JIVR4K5:~$ snap install firefox
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory"

Also the open commands do not work at my ubuntu due to which I am trying to open my html files from vs code in the browser directly from my vs code

**Kindly help me so that I will be able to run my html files typed in vs code from ubuntu to any browser either chrome or firefox** I am using Ubuntu WSL 2 version

Comment: are you physically on the computer that you are running this on?  Or is this over ssh? `Missing X server or $DISPLAY` seems to indicate there is a disconnect between the terminal and the UI.

Comment: I am physically on my computer but using Ubuntu as a virtual machine, till now I haven't figured out what the problem is.

Comment: Does this help? [Can't symlink to machine ID](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149989/1684306)

Comment: No it did not...